Implications of posting copyrighted material on Stack Exchange
Some people include their own creative work in SE questions. Examples could be a poem or music notation they are working on. Often it's material that hasn't been released or registered elsewhere.
What are the legal implications to their ability to the ability to protect and manage their copyrights, e.g. sell the content or the rights to reproduce it, and to prevent copyright violation?

Posting copyrighted material to StackExchange is more the rule than the exception. Even this very question is protected by copyright. "poem or music" suggests that copyright is limited to art forms, but that's not true.

@MSalters Of course you're right, and I'm sorry for not formulating it precisely enough. However certain realities are different. For example, I don't really care if someone posts this question on their website or uses it to train an LLM model. However, a content creator posting a question on SE might be significantly disappointed if e.g. it turns out to impact the ability to monetize their work.

@user1079505 You might not care, but that doesn't mean the copyright doesn't exist.

When it's their own work, they can do whatever they want with it, including sell licenses to their work. However, since anything posted on this site is under a CC-BY-SA license, everybody else can use the work as well, for free (providing they abide to the other parts of the license, such as naming the original author and sharing it under the same conditions "-SA").
So while the original author can sell licenses to their work, the recipient wouldn't need to pay for it, since it's already free. Of course, that only applies to the parts posted, not the whole work (e.g. if one just posts a single line of music, the CC-BY-SA license wouldn't apply to the whole opera score). If the recipient wants to use the work with a different license (e.g. without the "-SA" limitation, so they can use it as score for a commercial movie) then also other conditions and fees have to be agreed on.

The original author can also sell licenses that have different conditions. A recipient might be willing to pay if they want a license without the -SA conditions.

@BartvanIngenSchenau Absolutely true of course, added that.

You can still sell a license, but not every publisher will pay money for something if it's already freely available (publishers might insist that something has never been published previously). So there are practical implications to your ability to monetize your creations, but those are generally outside the scope of Law SE.

If the author did not intend to grant SE a CC-BY-SA license (for example, by posting it accidentally or by misunderstanding SE's TOS), things might get interesting.

@Heinzi Does not reading the TOS change the results of posting text? Can I get away with saying I did not know what I was doing so these terms actually don't apply to me?

@doneal24: No, you can't get away so easily. In general, (reasonable) TOS are binding whether you choose to read them or not. But those are just a contract between you and StackExchange. Somehow, I doubt that a court would force you to grant the whole world a royalty-free license for a creative work forever just because you made it available online for a short time with the wrong license attached to it due to an honest mistake. However, I have nothing to back up that assumption.

@Heinzi I have to disagree: courts have enforced license agreements that put a work under a very wide license, such as when posting a facebook image was giving any other facebook user blanket license to do whatever they wanted with it.
